# Selenium C# - Finding Elements in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I select the below element txtUsername in C# Selenium?

```
<td width="93" align="center" class="sidelink">
<input name="txtUsername" tabIndex="1" accessKey="U" style="width: 90%;" maxLength="50"/>
```

I have tried ID and Name, but the error returned that the element can't be found.

Is there a way to do this using Xpath? Note this is in I.E.

Help appreciated !

Comment: This is now resolved, I had to use driver.SwitchTo().Frame("leftside");

After switching to the correct frame, It managed to find the element by name.

Answer (score 0):

You cann't, because you are using HTML control you can use asp.net element like this

```
<asp:textbox id="textBox1" runat="server"></asp:textbox>
```

and use this code to get the text in the textbox

```
string s = textBox1.text;
```